# WhatsApp crashes after restoring messages

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, restore

My phone is a Moto G7 with an adopted 64 GB card. My WhatsApp constantly shows a message about something went wrong with your chat history, and I mean constantly, almost daily.

I do the trick of restoring and stopping the process when it reaches 35% and it worked fine...until now.  After restoring, it immediately shows the same message again.  Sometimes it complains about not having enough space. The restoration creates a lot of zero bytes video files. If I delete them, the process continues.

I have deleted the data, uninstalled it, and reinstalled it. Nothing works. If I reinstall and stop the process, it asks for my name, shows the initializing, and crashes again. If I let the restore run until the end, I get the well-known message about not being able to complete it.

**The only way to have it running again is to omit the restoration which it's obvious what I don't want** since like most of us, I have important messages.

I've read most questions about the problem but have been unable to find an answer, as AFAIK this bug has existed since forever on WhatsApp.

Any ideas on how to restore my messages?

*Edit*: After omitting the restoration, I put my phone on plane mode so it does not receive any pending messages

Comment: guess MicroSD card is the culprit

Comment: It crossed my mind @alecxs but everything but whatsapp is running fine. The backup could be indeed corrupt, but I've tried with three  different ones with the same result. I forgot to tell that once, only once, whatsapp started but apparently when the first message arrived, it crashed again. AFAIK whatsapp stores media and backups in the external storage, but the "main" data is written in the internal one

Comment: Solved. I won´t post it as an answer since I´m not sure if it will work again (I also hope not me nor anyone having the same problem) and also I was just guessing (in mexico we say "dar palos de ciego" strike with a blind man stick)
1.- Reinstalled
2.- Restored (stopped at 35%)
3.- Tried 1 and 2, plane mode, but same result, crashed so...
4.- Name it divine inspiration but after restoring I waited about ten minutes to open whats and that did the trick

P.D. I could tell when it won´t work since it didn't start to receive messages

Comment: I am facing the same issue... i don't get your solution..is it just waiting ten minutes after restoring then open the app.?

Comment: That worked but if it doesn't , try this: after restoration, switch to Whatsapp. If it is frozen, return to the previous screen and force termination again. Wait a few seconds, open and check if its is receiving messages.  A lot of them could arrive making it crash again, so I suggest terminate and opening in intervals until you see that no more messages arrive, then make a backup ASAP